# How to drop double header resulting from pivot in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem**

I've done a pivot table in pandas, but I end up with a double header when I export to csv.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'Product': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'net_sales': [55, 40, 84, 31, 56, 78, 34, 12]})
pvt_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['net_sales'], index=['Year'], columns=['Product'])
pvt_df.to_csv('sales.csv')
```

Which looks like below:

```
        net_sales   net_sales
Product A           B
Year        
1       55          56
2       40          78
3       84          34
4       31          12
```

**Desired Result**

What can I do to make the CSV export look like below?

```
Year    A           B
1       55          56
2       40          78
3       84          34
4       31          12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
pvt_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='net_sales', index='Year', columns='Product').reset_index()
pvt_df.to_csv('sales.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) with `axis=1` to drop a level from the columns:

```
>>> pvt_df.droplevel(0, axis=1)
Product   A   B
Year           
1        55  56
2        40  78
3        84  34
4        31  12

>>> pvt_df.droplevel(0, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
       A   B
Year        
1     55  56
2     40  78
3     84  34
4     31  12

>>> pvt_df.droplevel(0, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
   Year   A   B
0     1  55  56
1     2  40  78
2     3  84  34
3     4  31  12
```